# Multiple Conditionals in Poly ML

Tags: conditional-statements, sml, ml, polyml

If, for example, I wanted to define a function that returned true if a=b and b=c, and false if neither one of those equalities were true in Poly ML, how would I write it? I'm not sure how to do more than one conditional simultaneously.

Comment: What do you want to return if only one of the equalities is true?

Comment: Just "false"? Although, I asked around, and it seems to be that andalso is the thing to use.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this does what you need:

```
fun f (a, b, c) = 
  if a = b andalso b = c
  then true
  else
    if a <> b andalso b <> c
    then false
    else ... (* you haven't specified this case *)
```

The main points here are:

- You can nest conditionals, i.e. have one `if` expression inside another's `then` or `else` case
- The operator `andalso` is the boolean conjunction, meaning `x andalso y` is `true` if and only if `x` evaluates to `true` and `y` evaluates to `true`.

You can put this more concisely using a `case` expression:

```
fun f (a, b, c) =
  case (a = b, b = c) of
    (true, true) => true
  | (false, false) => false
  | _ => (* you haven't specified this case *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't

```
a = b andalso b = c
```

what you want?